# How can I backup my files in this situation (recovery mode)?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, terminal, disk-utility

My disk has been corrupted and has forced me load osx in recovery mode. Going to disk utility, I've tried verifying an image which needed repair. After attempting to repair, I've gotten to the following problem.

"Disk Utility can’t repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files."

How do I do this? From [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130304/how-can-i-repair-a-disk-that-disk-utility-says-it-cant-repair-this-disk), I've been told I can backup the disk from terminal, but **how can I get into terminal to backup my files of an unrepairable disk if I can't load into anything but recover mode?**

Any help would be really greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You attach a working drive along with the non-working drive, get an OS, then mount the non-working drive to recover the files